# Why does -O3 downcast/change the value of a const reference to a variable?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

class Test {
  public:
  Test(const int64_t & val) : val_(val) {
    std::cout << "initialized: " << val_ << std::endl;
  }
  void print() {std::cout << "reference val: " << val_ << std::endl;}

  private:
  const int64_t & val_;
};


int main() {
  long long int input_val= 1628020800000000000L;
  auto t = Test(input_val);
  std::cout << "input_val: " << input_val << std::endl; 
  t.print();
}
```

If you build without an optimized build you get the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++17
initialized: 1628020800000000000
input_val: 1628020800000000000
reference val: 1628020800000000000
```

If you build with an optimized build e.g. -O3, you get the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -O3
initialized: 1628020800000000000
input_val: 1628020800000000000
reference val: 0
```

I'm guessing this difference is due to the casting/treatment of `input_val` being of type `long long int`, but I do not really understand why that's the case. I thought a `long` was at least 32bit and a `long long` was at least twice as wide as a `long long`. Since the reference is a `const int64_t`, I thought there wouldn't be any casting issues.

I realize if I switch the `long long int` to an `int64_t`, this wouldn't be an issue, but I want to learn the reason as to why this happens.

g++/gcc version:

```
g++ (GCC) 9.1.1 20190605 (Red Hat 9.1.1-2) Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

*EDIT:*
The original version of this code had `input_val` (original `static_val`) as a global static variable. I changed the example to be simpler since the issue is not predicated on the variable being a global static var.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem is conversion.

`int64_t` is not the same thing as `long long int`.
So when this constructor is called: `Test(const int64_t & val)`
temporary value of type `int64_t` is created from `long long int`.

So result is `const int64_t & val_;` holds reference to temporary object which lifetime ends before `Test::print` is called.
Address sanitizer [finds issue quite nicely](https://godbolt.org/z/bvTjhdWca).

When you unify types it works: https://godbolt.org/z/nGKa6azE8

Note I've added to check what type of `int64_t` is and it matches  `long int` when building for 64 bits and `long long int` for 32 bit build.

Comment: Why does it work in a debug build vs an optimized build? The debug build just holds the reference for a longer period of time?

Comment: @ajoseps • doing it was [**undefined behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/4641116), and once you have that anything is possible.  Even appearing to work correctly.

Comment: cppreference says that `int64_t` is a `typedef` but It behaves as a distinct type with the same size as `long long int` (on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3nrYcexMT)). This was a surprise to me.

Comment: Ah ... got it. The `typedef` in this case is to `long int` which has the same size but is a distinct type (not the same as `long long int`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Meanwhile over on my Windows machine, `std::int64_t` typedefs to `long long` and your code sample fails to compile because it refuses to let me redefine a function. LP64 vs LLP64, I suppose. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) has a handy table folks may be interested in.